# Web Scraping: how can I add rows in a for loop to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape a table from the URLs below.
The scraping works but the problem I have is that it only shows the information from the first URL. How can I fix my code so that it adds the information of the second URL as well? I hope my question is clear.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://www.funda.nl/en/koop/ridderkerk/huis-42649106-natalstraat-15/', 'https://www.funda.nl/en/en/koop/rotterdam/huis-42648673-courzandseweg-67/']

#df = pd.DataFrame()

dl = []# Storage for data
dt = []# Storage for column names

for url in urls:
    headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36",}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, "html.parser")

    dl_data = soup.find_all("dd") # Scraping the data
    for dlitem in dl_data:
        dl.append(dlitem.text.strip())

    dt_data = soup.find_all("dt") # Scraping the column names
    for dtitem in dt_data:
        dt.append(dtitem.text.strip())


df = pd.DataFrame(dl) # Creating the dataframe

df = df.T # Transposing it because otherwise it is 1D
df.columns = dt # Giving the column names to the dataframe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the multiple lists, just choose a more leaner approached to process your data and save in more structured way e.g. `dict` - These `dict comprehension` selects all `<dd>` that follows an `<dt>` creates a `dict` and appends it to `data`. Simply create a `DataFrame` from this list of dicts:

```
data.append({e.find_previous_sibling('dt').text.strip(): e.text.strip() for e in soup.select('dt + dd')})
```

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://www.funda.nl/en/koop/ridderkerk/huis-42649106-natalstraat-15/', 'https://www.funda.nl/en/en/koop/rotterdam/huis-42648673-courzandseweg-67/']
data = []

for url in urls:
    headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36",}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, "html.parser")

    data.append({e.find_previous_sibling('dt').text.strip(): e.text.strip() for e in soup.select('dt + dd')})

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `dl` and `dt` do not have an equal amount of elements (75 and 71 respectively). Because of this, you can't use `dt` for column names. You could fix that by adding padding (for example initialising the `dt` list with zeros) or by removing unnecessary elements in the `dl` list.